# Can I book a flight from India to Latvia passing through Ukraine?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, ukraine, connecting-flights

Can I book a flight from India to Latvia passing through Ukraine? Do I need a visa in Ukraine?

Comment: Will you only transit in Ukraine or will visit Ukraine ?

Comment: Ukraine international Airlines serves Riga and Delhi (a few times per week). It certainly is cheap <500 US$  round trip.

Comment: Yeah i knw but i want visa to enter in Ukraine. Am i right ??

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are going to leave the transit zone, **no**, you do not need a visa. The only required documents are travel passport and boarding pass (so bother to check-in in advance).
This rule applies to all countries, not only India.

Here is [the map](https://kbp.aero/en/pass/transfer/) of transit area in Boryspil:

[image]

Otherwise, you do need a visa if you plan to exit KBP airport, as India citizens are required a visa to enter Ukraine.

You can apply for visa either in your country of residence or [directly in airport](http://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-boryspil).

Comment: Brother my question is if my connection flight arrived in Kiev airport . Are they ask me for my visa for Ukraine ?? Bcoz I entering into Ukraine airport so i need  Ukraine visa ???

Comment: @ZympleXBuildersPvtLtd read the answer attentively. No, you needn't, 'cause you only changing flights, as one can guess from your blurry words.

Answer (score 0):

Citizens of many countries can enter Ukraine without a visa with just a passport alone, for periods of up to 90 days out of 180:
USA, Canada, EU nations, United Kingdom, Switzerland, Japan, many countries of the former USSR. See complete list below.
Note that a few "first-world countries," namely Australia and New Zealand, aren't included in the list; citizens of these countries must obtain visas even for short visits.

[check here](https://www.tryukraine.com/info/visas/visas.shtml)